# Visual Studio code beautify format issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I'm using VS Code + js-beautify + Beautify css/sass/scss/less, and I'm facing couple of annoying issues when I format my code (don't know how to solve them):

1. This is NOT how I want my background color to look.
   From:

   ```
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
   ```

To:

```
    background-color: rgba(0,
    0,
    0,
    .0);
```

I want it to be format as one line (like "from").

2. The "cursor" property is in different color

   [image]

3. When I format my html code, there are line spaces in the body and the html.
   From:

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
       <head>
        <title>React App</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
      </body>
     </html>
   ```

To:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">

       <head>
        <title>React App</title>
       </head>

       <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
      </body>

     </html>
```

I want it to be formatted without any empty spaces (like "from").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is an old question, I was encountering the same issue and found the solution. In your VS Code `settings.json`, add the following to it:

```
"html.format.extraLiners": "",
```

By default nothing is there so it will default to `html, body, /html`. By setting it to nothing, it will give you the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can change format settings in VS Code's settings.json file. By default, head, body and html tags include a newline before them. If some issues started happening only after installing an extension, then there may be conflicting settings.

Comment: Thanks. Any specific settings you know?